# sqlite3.OperationalError: near ":45": syntax error with datetime

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/hacker47/Documents/programming/python/ubin/sql_c.py", line 11, in 
url_cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO url(Date,Time,Urls) VALUES ({datetime.today().strftime('%B_%d_%Y')},{datetime.today().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}, '1')")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ":45": syntax error

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime


url_con = sqlite3.connect("url.db")

url_cursor = url_con.cursor()

print(f"INSERT INTO url VALUES ({datetime.today().strftime('%B_%d_%Y')}, {datetime.today().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}, 1)")

url_cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO url(Date,Time,Urls) VALUES ({datetime.today().strftime('%B_%d_%Y')},{datetime.today().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}, '1')")

url_con.commit()

url_con.close()
```

Comment: Sqlite doesn't understand the time format like e. g. "07:14:25"

Comment: Don't use f-strings or other string formatting techniques to interpolate values into queries, use parameter substitution as described in the  answers to the linked duplicate.

Comment: it is give me this sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error